# Forbid mouse pointer to go to second monitor windows 10 while in extend mode?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I am using windows 10 **extend** mode for my *second monitor*. I am using full screen browser mode on my *primary monitor* to play a game and have dragged a video to my *second monitor*.

After I have dragged my video (which is now playing) to my *second monitor*, I want to forbid my mouse pointer to be able to cross over from my *primary monitor* on to my *second monitor* which is the default behaviour with this **extend** mode.

Is there any way I can assign prefferably a **hotkey** to disable this behaviour and lock my mouse pointer to my *primary monitor*?